# program skips a user input when calling the function

Tags: c++

I have a class called Route inside the class I have a member function that when it is called in main It should ask the user some questions,
for example when I call the function it displays:

```
Please enter the name of the address:
Please enter the time you want to leave:
Please enter the arrival time:

//this is the function//
Route create_route() {

    Route route_;
    std::string name;
    unsigned short int time;


    std::cout << "Please enter the name of the address: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    cin.ignore();
    route_.set_name(name);


    std::cout << "Please enter the time you want to leave: ";
    std::cin >> time;
    std::cin.ignore();
    route_.set_departure_time(time);


    std::cout << "Please enter the arrival time: ";
    std::cin >> time;
    std::cin.ignore();
    route_.set_arrival_time(time);

    return route_;
    }
    int main() {
    create_route();
    }
```

when I run the program it skips the fist user input, I've tired to put

```
cin.ignore();
```

after the first user input and it works but then skips the second one :( if I put cin.ignore(); after every user input it still does not work any advise would help a lot!

Comment: `inside the class I have a member function` does that function have a signature, and documented/commented source code to go?

Comment: Here's some advice: before posting your first question you should've taken a [tour] of stackoverflow.com first, read the [help]'s suggestions for [ask] questions correctly, and review the requirements for a [mre]. Since this did not happen, this question is unlikely to be answered in a way that'll help you. But it's not too late -- after reading the links I just gave you, you can simply [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Works on my machine.  Maybe your code has a bug in it, but it is hard to tell since you've only showed us one line of your code.  I did not need to use that line in my code.

Comment: I've added the function :)

Comment: This code does not reproduce the reported error. Remember garbage in, garbage out. Give us bad information and you'll receive bad responses. Before placing an `ignore` (or any other make any other code change in response to a bug), Explain to [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) how this will solve your problem. Rubber ducks are notoriously slow learners so you'll have to explain carefully. If your plan still makes sense after explaining it to Duckie, odds are good that it'll work.If not, go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling `cin.ignore()` after calling `std::getline()`, only after calling `operator>>`. If you are calling `ignore()` to skip a line break, you should be passing `'\n'` as the delimiter for `ignore()`:

```cpp
Route create_route() {
    Route route_;
    std::string name;
    unsigned short int time;

    std::cout << "Please enter the name of the address: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    route_.set_name(name);

    std::cout << "Please enter the time you want to leave: ";
    std::cin >> time;
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    route_.set_departure_time(time);

    std::cout << "Please enter the arrival time: ";
    std::cin >> time;
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    route_.set_arrival_time(time);

    return route_;
}
```

Alternatively, use `std::getline()` to read all of the inputs, and `std::istringstream` to parse them:

```cpp
Route create_route() {
    Route route_;
    std::string input;
    unsigned short int time;

    std::cout << "Please enter the name of the address: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    route_.set_name(input);

    std::cout << "Please enter the time you want to leave: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::istringstream(input) >> time;
    route_.set_departure_time(time);

    std::cout << "Please enter the arrival time: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::istringstream(input) >> time;
    route_.set_arrival_time(time);

    return route_;
}
```